# Does Gringotts employ any non-goblins?

Tags: harry-potter, gringotts

I'm asking for a friend, a wizard who until recently worked at the Apothecary in Diagon Alley, but is really interested in banking, like his Muggle cousin who made millions of dollars working for a bank.  Anyway, he's trying to stay local in DiagonAlley, and he wants to know if they employ non-goblins before he tries for an interview.  Thanks!

Comment: For a "friend". Right.

Comment: @Xantec Of course

Comment: this answers your question, slight dupe http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13148/what-jobs-can-wizards-and-witches-do-within-the-world-of-magic/13155#13155

Comment: Everybody has a "friend" that refers to self.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Gringotts offers several jobs opportunities to non-Goblins, but they may not help your friend so much.

- Dragons

  > They say there’s dragons guardin’ the high security vaults
  >   (*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 5*)
- Sphinxes

  > GRIPE WITH GRINGOTT’S BANK
  >   Dear Sir,
  >   Am I alone in wondering why Gringott’s Bank has recently (...) I was taken aback to find one of these creatures standing guard outside my own vault on my last visit. (...) As I failed to answer every one of the sphinx’s riddles, I was unable to get past it to my gold.
  >   -- Mallory Twiddle
  >   (*[Daily Prophet 1](http://beta.hp-lexicon.org/dp1), "[Gripe with Gringott's Bank](http://beta.hp-lexicon.org/item/gripe-with-gringotts-bank/)"*)
- Security Trolls

  > [Paraphrased:] I would personal prefer the return of dragons or security trolls to the front line at Gringott's Wizarding Bank
  >   (*[Daily Prophet 1](http://beta.hp-lexicon.org/dp1), "[Gripe with Gringott's Bank](http://beta.hp-lexicon.org/item/gripe-with-gringotts-bank/)"*)
- Curse-Breakers

  > Are you seeking a challenging career involving travel, adventure and substantial, danger-related treasure bonuses? Then consider a position with Gringotts Wizarding Bank, who are currently recruiting Curse-Breakers for thrilling opportunities abroad…
  >   (*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 29*)
- Desk Jobs

  > “Is Bill here?” he asked. “I thought he was working in Egypt?”
  >   “He applied for a desk job so he could come home and work for the Order,” said Fred.
  >   (*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 12*)
- Dragon Feeders

  > DRAGON FEEDERS
  >   Needed by Gringotts Bank. No qualifications necessary. Fireproof robes and balaclava provided. Apply in writing giving names of next of kin. Salary: 7 Galleons per week.
  >   (*[Daily Prophet 2](http://beta.hp-lexicon.org/dp2), "[Classified: Jobs](http://beta.hp-lexicon.org/item/classified-advertisements/)"*)
- Management

  > HOW FAR WILL FUDGE GO TO GAIN GRINGOTTS?
  >   Cornelius Fudge, the Minister for Magic, denied that he had any plans to take over the running of the Wizarding Bank, Gringotts, when he was elected Minister for Magic five years ago. Fudge has always insisted that he wants nothing more than to ‘co-operate peacefully’ with the guardians of our gold.
  >   BUT DOES HE?
  >   Sources close to the Minister have recently disclosed that Fudge’s dearest ambition is to seize control of the goblin gold supplies and that he will not hesitate to use force if need be.
  >   “It wouldn’t be the first time, either,” said a Ministry insider. “Cornelius ‘Goblin-Crusher’ Fudge, that’s what his friends call him. If you could hear him when he thinks no one’s listening, oh, he’s always talking about the goblins he’s had done in; he’s had them drowned, he’s had them dropped off buildings, he’s had them poisoned, he’s had them cooked in pies…”
  >   (*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 10*)

Of course not all of these jobs would be the best for your friend. He may not be a Dragon, Troll, or Sphinx. He may not be cut out to be working abroad curse-breaking. Your friend may dislike boring desk jobs, or to afraid to feed dragons. In truth Gringotts saves their best jobs for fellow Goblins. However this could change. You may want to show your friend [this flyer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/117720/55866).

Comment: Though the quote from the Quibbler proves nothing

Comment: How do you make a link to an individual answer?

Comment: @CHEESE I use the share button on the bottom of answers. (I still have no idea how to get the link to a comment, though)

Comment: @ibid In the (iOS) app, there's a _Share_ button on comments too, but on the website, I don't believe there is a very simple and intuitive way. (Also, how does the Fudge quote say anything about Gringotts hiring non-goblins for management? It only mentions Fudge denying claims that he was trying to take over the bank by force, as far as I can tell.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I included the Fudge one more of as a joke. (That's why I put it last, and didn't bother addressing it in the conclusion.)

Comment: Incidentally, in case you hadn’t figured it out yet, the way to link directly to a comment from the website is simple: the time stamp. Just right-click and copy the link, and there’s your direct link.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I figured out a couple days after asking. I considered updating, but felt it would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 58):

Yes. The most famous example of a non-Goblin employee at Gringotts is Bill Weasley.

It's referred to several times, but I think the first reference I can find is in *Chamber of Secrets* chapter 4:

> Harry had never met either of them, but knew that Charlie was in Romania, studying dragons, and Bill in Egypt, working for the wizards’ bank, Gringotts.

And fret not if curse-breaking isn't your friend's forte, for they also have desk jobs, which Mr. Weasley transferred to when moving back to Britain during the second struggle against Voldemort.

From *Order of the Phoenix*, also chapter 4:

> ‘Is Bill here?’ he asked. ‘I thought he was working in Egypt?’
>   ‘He applied for a desk job so he could come home and work for the Order,’ said Fred. ‘He says he misses the tombs, but,’ he smirked, ‘there are compensations.’

Comment: Add to this in the movies, we see a security guard approach hermione disguised as bellatrix when they are attempting to infiltrate the bank vaults. Not cannon, but still some supporting material.

Comment: The first reference is in *Philosopher's Stone* when Ron tells Harry about his brothers on the Hogwarts Express: *"Charlie's in Romania studying dragons, and Bill's in Africa doing something for Gringotts," said Ron.*

Answer (score 48):

I consider the [dragon](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gringott's_Dragon) a non-goblin employee of Gringotts. While it might not be a very well treated employee, I've seen some companies treat their employees worse.

[image]

Comment: I...I mean, my friend...is not a dragon, but that counts.  if I know any dragons, i'll tell them

Comment: Don't they also have trolls?

Comment: My friend is human, guys!

Comment: @CHEESE not even a little bit of troll blood?

Comment: Employees are paid and allowed to leave. That dragon was a slave.

Comment: @RedCaio Technically they did allow it to leave the bank on the one day of its employment/slavery there. We don't know for sure that wasn't a daily occurrence…

Answer (score 18):

[image]

According to the films at least, they hire human security. Your friend could say he was there for that role if they laugh at him for the banking job.

Comment: I don't think they're employed by Gringotts. They're placed there by the ministry since the death eater-led ministry didn't trust or respect goblins (or any non-pureblood human)s.

Comment: Are those things that they carry on their left hips holsters for their wands? The left hip might not be the right place for this (unless all guards happen to be left-handed), but it still looks pretty sweet.

Comment: @RedCaio - That's an interesting thought. Or do you think maybe Gringotts hired extra security in those troubled times? Hmm, you're probably right though.

Comment: @Thomas Jacobs - I think so. Several Death Eater costumes had wand holsters so they certainly existed in the film world. Definitely cool. And personally I think if I had a wand on my left hip I would probably draw it with my right hand. Different feel to a gun.

Comment: see [were-the-gringotts-guards-hired-by-the-goblins-or-the-ministry?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117712/were-the-gringotts-guards-hired-by-the-goblins-or-the-ministry)

Comment: @ThomasJacobs It is probably a crossdraw holster, in which the weapon is carried on the side opposite of one's strong hand. The person reaches across their body to draw, as one would draw a sword. It's not common (look at any cop or armed security guard - most carry on their strong side) but it does happen. Wild Bill Hickok was famous for carrying his guns this way. https://www.usconcealedcarry.com/mastering-the-crossdraw/