# Who hired the Gringotts Guards - the goblins, or the Ministry?

Tags: harry-potter, gringotts

> Gringotts Guards are wizards who are assigned to guard the entrance of Gringotts, the bank of the wizarding world.
>
> During the Death Eaters' reign over the wizarding world, security was tightened, and guards used Probity Probe to search anyone attempting to enter the bank.
>
> <sub>- Harry Potter wiki [Gringotts Guards](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gringotts_Guards)</sub>

However it doesn't say *who* assigned them to guard the bank. Was it the Goblins' decision or was it *imposed* upon them by the Death Eater-led ministry?

[image]

Comment: just for the record, that muggle police officer/security guard look is 100% a movie thing. still good question and ibid has given an excellent answer

Comment: @Au101 movie or not, I really liked those wand holsters. Does anyone sell them?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### It was imposed upon them by the Death Eater-led ministry.

To quote Griphook:

> “But it is, it is precisely that! **As the Dark Lord becomes ever more powerful, your race is set still more firmly above mine! Gringotts falls under Wizarding rule**, house-elves are slaughtered, and who amongst the wand-carriers protests?”
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 24*- [text available on Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/bargaining-with-griphook))</sub>

Security at Gringotts was usually controlled exclusively by Goblins. Under Voldemort's reign, however, they were forced to yield those jobs to Wizards.

> As Griphook had already warned them, **the liveried goblins who usually flanked the entrance had been replaced by two wizards**, both of whom were clutching long thin golden rods.
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 26*)</sub>

Goblins considered themselves neutral and desired no part in wizard's conflict.

> There was another pause in which the fire crackled and the river rushed on. Then Ted said, “And where do you two fit in? **I, er, had the impression the goblins were for You-Know-Who, on the whole.”
>
>   “You had a false impression,” said the higher-voiced of the goblins. “We take no sides. This is a wizards’ war**.”
>   “How come you’re in hiding, then?”
>   “I deemed in prudent,” said the deeper-voiced goblin. “Having refused what I considered an impertinent request, I could see that my person safety was in jeopardy.”
>   “What did they ask you to do?” asked Ted.
>   “**Duties ill-befitting the dignity of my race,” replied the goblin, his voice rougher and less human as he said it. “I am not a house-elf**.”
>   “What about you, Griphook?”
>   “Similar reasons,” said the higher voiced goblin. “**Gringotts is no longer under the sole control of my race. I recognize no Wizarding master**.”
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 15*)</sub>

It should be noted that Gringotts did hire wizards, even if not in security positions.

> “I know goblins,” said Bill. “**I've worked for Gringotts ever since I left Hogwarts**. As far as there can be friendship between wizards and goblins, I have goblin friends -- or, at least, goblins I know well, and like.”
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 25*)</sub>